# Ionic/Angular 2 component event emitter not updating view

Tags: cordova, datepicker, angular, ionic2, angular2-components

I am currently writing an Ionic 2 app and have created the following custom component:

```
import {Component, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';
import {Button, Icon, Item} from 'ionic-angular';
import {DatePicker} from 'ionic-native';
import {HSDatePipe} from '../pipes/custom-dateformat.pipe';

@Component({
    selector: 'date-picker',
    directives: [Button, Icon, Item],
    inputs: ['date', 'dateFormat', 'mode'],
    outputs: ['onUpdate'],
    pipes: [HSDatePipe],
    template: `<button clear (click)="selectDate()">
        {{date | hsDate:dateFormat}}
    </button>`
})
export class HSDatePicker {

    date:any;
    dateFormat:any;
    label:string;
    mode:string;
    onUpdate:any = new EventEmitter();

    constructor() {
    }

    selectDate() {
        let self:any = this;
        let previousDate:any = self.date;

        DatePicker.show({
            date: new Date(self.date),
            mode: self.mode
        })
        .then(
            (date:any) => {
                if (!date) {
                    date = previousDate;
                }
                self.onUpdate.emit(date);
            },
            err => {
                console.log('error -', err);
            }
        );
    }

}
```

On the page calling this component, I include it in the page like so:

```
<date-picker item-right [date]="period.dateEnd" [dateFormat]="'HH:mm'" [mode]="'time'" (onUpdate)="dateChange($event, 'dateEnd')"></date-picker>
```

The `dateChange` function looks like this:

```
dateChange(e, selector) {
    let newDate = moment(e);
    this.transactionFilter[selector] = newDate;
}
```

When I use the component to select a new date, the function is called as I would expect, and the transactionFilter object is updated. However, the view doesn't update and it still displays the old date on the page until I click a button, or focus an input etc.

I think the problem is to do with the DatePicker plugin or promises, because if I change the `selectDate()` function like so, it updates fine.

```
selectDate() {
    let self:any = this;
    self.onUpdate.emit(new Date());
}
```

Is there a way to force the view to update or should I do it differently somehow?

Thanks for any help.

Edit: Template for the main page

```
@Page({
    template: `
    <ion-content>
        <ion-toolbar primary class="subheader">
            <ion-title>Transaction Viewer Filter</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-icon name="calendar" item-left></ion-icon>
                From
                <date-picker item-right [date]="transactionFilter.fromDate" [dateFormat]="'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'" [mode]="'datetime'" (onUpdate)="dateChange($event, 'fromDate')"></date-picker>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-icon name="calendar" item-left></ion-icon>
                To
                <date-picker item-right [date]="transactionFilter.toDate" [dateFormat]="'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'" [mode]="'datetime'" (onUpdate)="dateChange($event, 'toDate')"></date-picker>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
                Count: {{count}}
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col>
                <button class="close-modal" (click)="close()" danger block>Close</button>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col>
                <button class="save-modal" (click)="save()" favorite block>Save</button>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-content>`,
    directives: [HSDatePicker]
})
```

Comment: what version of the ionic beta are you using?

Comment: `ionic -v` displays 2.0.0-beta.25

Comment: In your project route type `ionic info` to get the details of that project. I think `ionic -v` is the CLI version

Comment: Ah sorry, Ionic Framework version is 2.0.0-beta.6. Ionic App lib version is beta 15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it's because Angular2 detects changes based on references and not on values. If a new instance of date is detected, the view will be updated. If it's the same instance but its content is updated, the view won't be updated.

I would recreate a new date like this:

```
DatePicker.show({
  date: new Date(self.date),
  mode: self.mode
})
.then(
  (date:any) => {
    if (!date) {
      date = previousDate;
    }
    self.onUpdate.emit(new Date(date.getTime()));
  },
  err => {
    console.log('error -', err);
  }
);
```

**Edit**

You could try to execute your processing in a zone:

```
export class HSDatePicker {

    date:any;
    dateFormat:any;
    label:string;
    mode:string;
    onUpdate:any = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(private ngZone:NgZone) { // <-------
    }

    selectDate() {
      this.ngZone.run(() => { // <------
        let self:any = this;
        let previousDate:any = self.date;

        DatePicker.show({
            date: new Date(self.date),
            mode: self.mode
        })
        .then(
            (date:any) => {
                if (!date) {
                    date = previousDate;
                }
                self.onUpdate.emit(date);
            },
            err => {
                console.log('error -', err);
            }
        );
      });
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution but the view still doesn't update unfortunately.

Comment: I think that you should execute things within a zone. I updated my answer accordingly...

Comment: Same problem :( it updates the object inside `dateChange()` fine, just the view doesn't update. I also tried just setting `this.transactionFilter[selector]` to `new Date()` and ignored the incoming parameter, but it still was the same thing.

Comment: Could you show me the corresponding block in the template? Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my question with the template, is that what you meant? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Does the datepicker supports two-way binding? Something like: `<date-picker item-right [(date)]="transactionFilter.fromDate" [dateFormat]="'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'" [mode]="'datetime'" (onUpdate)="dateChange($event, 'fromDate')"></date-picker>`

Comment: Ah you pointed me in the right direction and the ngZone worked, thanks very much! I'll accept your answer and then post what I did. Basically I had to move where the ngZone.run function ran.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `selectDate()` function like so and it works now. Thanks to Thierry & this post [ionic2-camera-demo](https://github.com/marcusasplund/ionic2-camera-demo/blob/master/app/pages/page1/page1.ts) for pointing me in the right direction.

```
selectDate() {

        let self:any = this;
        let previousDate = self.date;

        DatePicker.show({
            date: new Date(self.date),
            mode: self.mode
        })
        .then(
            (date:any) => {
                if (!date) {
                    date = previousDate;
                }
                this.ngZone.run(() => {
                    self.onUpdate.emit(date);
                });
            },
            err => {
                console.log('error -', err);
            }
        );

    }
```